# Unicode-decode error utf-8 para ñ en python

Tags: python, unicode, anaconda

Tengo error en la consola python al intentar instalar paquetes y demás 
y me tira el error unicode-decode error ya que el usuario en mi computadora
tiene el caracter Ñ que es de mi apellido.

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while installing package 'None'. 
UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8', 
    b'C:\\Users\\VILLAFA\xd1E\\Anaconda3\\envs\\untitled \r\nC:\\Users\\VILLAFA\xd1E\\Anaconda3\\envs\\py\r\nC:\\Users\\VILLAFA\xd1E\\Ana conda3\\envs\\py27\r\nC:\\Users\\VILLAFA\xc3\x91E\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\r \nC:\\Users\\VILLAFA\xc3\x91E\\Anaconda3\\envs\\udacity\r\n', 
    16, 17, 'invalid c ontinuation byte') 
Attempting to roll back.
```

El PATH es el siguiente

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Driver;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Statgraphics\STATGRAPHICS Centurion XVI.I\;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Users\VILLAFAÑE\Anaconda3;C:\Users\VILLAFAÑE\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\VILLAFAÑE\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Me ha salido con todos los paquetes que he querido instalar, la version de python q estoy usando es la 3.7.0. Ya copio el código para compartirlo...

Comment: No pude desde la consola de python, pero lo busque en la configuración de python. La voy a pegar en el mensaje arriba

Comment: con agregar esto al empiezo del documento debe funcionarte
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` o puedes hacer un `str.decode('utf8')`

Answer (score 0):

Parece que los caracteres no ascii en la ruta de instalación de Anaconda plantean problemas. Hay varios [reportes](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1613) en Github sobre este asunto, y ninguna solución buena, salvo la de crear un nuevo usuario sin esos caracteres en el nombre (no me parece una opción), o la de instalar Anaconda fuera de la ruta de ese usuario (esta podría ser mejor opción).

En la [FAQ de Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#installing-anaconda) puede leerse (la traducción y la negrita es mía):

> **¿En qué carpeta debería instalar Anaconda en Windows?**
>
> Recomendamos instalar Anaconda o Minicoda en una carpeta **que contenga sólo caracteres ASCII y sin espacios**, como `C:\anaconda`. No lo instale en rutas que contengan espacios, como `C:\Program Files` o `C:\Archivos de Programa`, o que contengan caracteres Unicode fuera del rango del ASCII de 7 bits. Esto ayuda a asegurar un correcto funcionamiento y la ausencia de errores cuando se use cualquier herramienta open source, tanto en entornos conda Python 2 como Python 3.

Y quizás pueda ser también relevante:

> **¿Debo añadir Anaconda al PATH de Windows?**
>
> Cuando instale Anaconda, recomendamos que no añada Anaconda al PATH de windows, porque eso puede interferir con otro software. En lugar de ello, abra Anaconda desde el menú de Inicio de Windows, seleccionando `Anaconda Prompt`, o use *Anaconda Navigator*.

Como recomendación extra, tras reinstalar Anaconda en la ruta correcta, te recomendaría que editaras las variables de entorno de Windows y buscaras si aún queda en el PATH o en otras variables alguna referencia a tu antigua carpeta en la ruta con eñes, para quitarlas también.